# How to remove files tab from html file generated by doxygen?

Tags: doxygen

I have been using doxygen to generate html document for my project. And my generated documents contain a files tab. How could I remove that files tab.?

Apart from that I also want to remove all hyperlinks that directs to a code page. Thanks in advance.

I want to remove this part of documentation

The documentation for this class was generated from the following files:

```
D:/xyx/entities/ClassA.h
D:/xyx/entities/ClassA.cxx
```

here I have a hyperlink for ClassA.h

Answer (score 8):

Put the following line into your Doxyfile:

```
 SHOW_FILES = NO
```

Comment: I think the  best option is to have 

VERBATIM_Header = NO

SOURCE_BROWSER  = NO

SHOW_INCLUDE_FILE  = YES

SHOW_USED_FILE  = YES


It worked for me.

Comment: When I set `SHOW_FILES = NO` my @ref tags no longer work.  I tried the solution Apoorva suggested but the file list was still generated.  The @ref tags I am used refer to enumeration values - I have not tried any other @ref tags.

Answer (score 3):

To remove the files tab you can customize the html layout used by Doxygen.

- Generate a default layout file with `doxygen -l` in the folder where your Doxyfile is, this will create a file named DoxygenLayout.xml
- In the generated layout file, change `visible` to `no` in the following line:
  `<tab type="files" visible="yes"`
- Run doxygen again, the layout file will be read from Doxygen without having to change the Doxyfile as long as it has the default name.

Answer (score 3):

```
SHOW_FILES = NO
```

would remove files page from Quick Index, to remove the source file used for the documentation from the bottom of the page use

```
SHOW_USED_FILES = NO
```

Answer (score 0):

The answers are helpful but there the EXTRACT_ALL option that generates the Class List and File list for me. 
Try disabling EXTRACT_ALL. It worked for me